# Error Code: 1060 Duplicate column name 'fsu_id' in the attached mysql view

Tags: mysql, view, sqlyog

I am receiving Error Code: 1060 Duplicate column name 'fsu_id' in the attached view that I am trying to create even the field names are pre-fixed.

I am creating the view using tool called SQLyog.

The tables `bkd` and `rcs` are actually views I have previously created.

```
CREATE
/*[ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
[SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]*/
VIEW `arab_cargo_fsu`.`rcs_after_bkd` 
AS
(SELECT
`bkd`.`fsu_id`
, `bkd`.`msg_id`
, `bkd`.`msg_date_time`    
, `rcs`.`fsu_id`
, `rcs`.`msg_id`
, `rcs`.`msg_date_time`        
FROM
`arab_cargo_fsu`.`bkd`
LEFT JOIN `arab_cargo_fsu`.`rcs` 
    ON (`bkd`.`pfx` = `rcs`.`pfx`) AND (`bkd`.`awb` = `rcs`.`awb`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a view/table where columns have the same name. Use aliases

```
SELECT bkd.fsu_id as bkd_fsu_id,
       ...
       rcs.fsu_id as rcs_fsu_id
       ...
```

Comment: Actually I tried just that and the same error occurred.

Comment: Did you use an alias on all 3 duplicate columns?